# How can I sort this array of hashes using a secondary array of strings?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I have an array of hashes that looks like this:

```
user_array = [<#Hashie::Mash id="1" name="Ben">, <#Hashie::Mash id="2" name="Scott">, <#Hashie::Mash id="3" name="David">]
```

And I also have an array that contains IDs pulled from an external source:

```
freq_array = ["1","2","2","3","2","3"]
```

I need to use `freq_array` to order `user_array`, so that the user whose ID appears the most in `freq_array` is first in the `user_array`. So based on the above `freq_array`, `user_array` would be

```
user_array = [<#Hashie::Mash id="2" name="Scott">, <#Hashie::Mash id="3" name="David">, <#Hashie::Mash id="1" name="Ben">]
```

What is the best way to do this? Thanks for reading.

EDIT: I got the format of the user_array hashes wrong. Have corrected.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
user_array.sort_by { |user| freq_array.count(user["id"]) * -1 }
```

Comment: `user_array.sort_by { |user| -freq_array.count(user["id"]) }`

Comment: that's shorter ;) I can make it more readable too: `user_array.sort_by { |user| freq_array.count(user["id"]) }.reverse` It is slower, but clearer what's going on imho

Comment: Thanks for the answers guys. The count is working okay, but the user_array isn't actually being ordered at all. I realised that each entry in the user_array actually looks slightly different to how I showed in the question. I've edited the question to reflect this.

Comment: Don't worry, got it working, stupid mistake by me. Thanks guys!

Comment: When using Enumerable#sort and sort_by I've always missed a "reverse" boolean option.

Comment: If you must: `module Enumerable; def inverse_sort(&block); sort(&lambda { |a,b| -block.call(a,b) }); end; end`